# Tiny private cloud solution

Tags: cloud, private, virtualization

I work in a small company with a few developers. I want to create a small private cloud to allow them to easily create VMs for testing and development (public cloud is not an options). Specifically I'm looking for a solution to:

- Start and stop VMs based on predefined images, using Web interface
- View and control the state of the VMs
- Be able to configure the instances (Linux & Win) using cloud-init or similar method
- Basic networking (all machines on the same networkd is perfectly good)

Openstack & Cloudstack seem a bit of an overkill for that purpose, especially due to the fact that I have currently a single server and no plans to purchase more.

Is there any solution out there to such a problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the term "private cloud?"  Can you consider a hypervisor running on a machine you own in your office?  Xen (citrix) and VMWare both make decent virtualization systems with a free entry level offering.

Comment: That would require me to give the root password to all users. Additionally, it does not solve the provisioning problem (cloud-init) - every user will have to configure its own instance manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [Xen Orchestra](https://xen-orchestra.com/#!/). It's a Web interface to Xen Server that allows users to easily start, stop and control VMs. cloud-init support included.
Unfortunately, the feature that allows users to control their VMs without admin password (self service) costs 500$/month.

Answer (score 0):

You can create xen server for that purpose.

Install and configure xen on your server and allow developer to create vm and connect to them.

For more detail,

https://www.citrix.co.in/products/xenserver/